# Calculate age in Foundation-datepicker.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, jquery-calculation

I'm using Foundation-datepicker.js in my form as an easy datepicking tool. Always worked great for me. But now the client wants me make it so that visitors can only select dates that are 18 years ago (minimum age of 18).

I'm guessing I have to use the minView|maxView options. But I can't seem to find the right syntax for it.

Any ideas? My function so far is pretty easy:

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').fdatepicker({
       language: 'nl',  
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
       disableDblClickSelection: true
    });
});
```

I tried this as a test

```
$(function(){
    $('#date').fdatepicker({
       language: 'nl',  
       format: 'dd-mm-yyyy',
       disableDblClickSelection: true,
       maxView: 'year' = 3
    });
});
```

But that doesn't do it for me.

Find the documentation here: 
http://foundation-datepicker.peterbeno.com/example.html

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the page you posted the link to under the "No Inputs" heading there is this line of code which I believe is the solution:

```
    $(function(){
  // implementation of custom elements instead of inputs
    var startDate = new Date(2012, 1, 20);
    var endDate = new Date(2012, 1, 25);
    $('#dp4').fdatepicker()
        .on('changeDate', function (ev) {
        if (ev.date.valueOf() > endDate.valueOf()) {
            $('#alert').show().find('strong').text('The start date can not be greater then the end date');
        } else {
            $('#alert').hide();
            startDate = new Date(ev.date);
            $('#startDate').text($('#dp4').data('date'));
        }
        $('#dp4').fdatepicker('hide');
    });
```

According to what I can see here you can customise start and end dates with the variables (var startDate) and (endDate).